# Why do the changes introduced by a commit not show up in my working tree?

Tags: git

I'm having an issue where git says a commit is merged, but the
changes from the commit aren't in my working tree. To make things even weirder,
`git log --name-status 362dde7` tells me that the commit modified a file, but
`git log -- path/to/modified/file.java` does not show the commit. For example:

Ensure that the commit in question exists on both the dev branch and feature branch.

```
$ git branch --contains 362dde74f142831c99820b999558a2e8f49f66e8
* dev
  feature
```

List the files modified by the commit.

```
$ git show --name-status 362dde74f142831c99820b999558a2e8f49f66e8
# commit summary... #
M       path/to/modified/file.java
```

Now when I do the reverse (list the commits that have modified the file) the commit isn't listed.

```
$ git log path/to/modified/file.java
# Commit 362dde7 isn't listed here
```

If I switch to the feature branch and follow the same steps, everything works as expected.

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git show --name-status 362dde74f142831c99820b999558a2e8f49f66e8
# commit summary... #
M       path/to/modified/file.java
$ git log path/to/modified/file.java
362dde7 Commit summary
```

Basically, the same commit exists on both `dev` and `feature`, but the working tree changes only show up when I have `feature` checked out. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe the file has been deleted and then, a few commits later, restored back in the branch? Do `git log --stat` and search for the file name.

Comment: @kan Thanks for the tip, but no luck. There's only one other commit that created the file and then commit 362dde7 that modified it.

Comment: Maybe merge has been done with `--strategy ours`? Does the file content differ?

Comment: @kan The file content differs in my working tree depending on if I have dev or feature checked out. However, doing git show for that commit is identical for both branches (as expected). Also, there are no other later commits that touch this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git init so19234836
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/g/so19234836/.git/
$ cd so19234836/
$ echo "content created" > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m c1
[master (root-commit) a965818] c1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git checkout -b feature
Switched to a new branch 'feature'
$ echo "feature change"> file
$ git commit -am f1
[feature eaf4121] f1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git checkout master 
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge -s ours feature
Merge made by the 'ours' strategy.
```

Now I have similar state of the repo:

```
$ git log file
commit a965818706c47d065b81a994aeb5fc24cd77d001
Author: Anatoly Kupriyanov <kan.izh@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 7 22:44:52 2013 +0100

    c1
$ git checkout feature 
Switched to branch 'feature'
$ git log file
commit eaf41212872d784d4e4e50e62167072d35b6167f
Author: Anatoly Kupriyanov <kan.izh@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 7 22:49:02 2013 +0100

    f1

commit a965818706c47d065b81a994aeb5fc24cd77d001
Author: Anatoly Kupriyanov <kan.izh@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 7 22:44:52 2013 +0100

    c1

$ git branch --contains eaf41212872d784d4e4e50e62167072d35b6167f
* feature
  master
```

So, basically if you do a merge from another branch but revert any changes in the merge commit for the file, content is not changed, but merged commits appear in the history.

Comment: Suggest replacing 'kan@altegol:/tmp/g/so19234836$' with '$'

Comment: Thanks! This definitely explains it. Rereading the git-log docs I noticed that "git log -- <path>" will "show _only_ commits that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be." That's why it doesn't list the commit when I'm on my dev branch.

Answer (score 4):

Try it again with `--full-history`.  When `git log` is hunting for commits that modified a path, by default it does [history simplification](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_history_simplification), which is to say it doesn't show any commits from which all changes are easily seen to have been either dropped or already merged (and those latter therefore appear in some other commit git's going to list anyway).

Consider this graph, with commits identified by the content of "path":

```
 o---o---A---A---B  master HEAD
  \         /
   o---X---Y        topic
```

The idea is, git presumes something in your current checkout prompted you to hunt down the source of changes in the checked out file — and if, at a merge point, no change from one parent appears in the merge result, nothing in that parent's history affected your copy of the file.

Think cherry-picks and squash merges and rejected changes and widely-disseminated hotfixes and multiple pull sources.